# ZMQ bind_to_random_port is not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, pyzmq

I have the following code:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)

communication_string = "{protocol}".format(protocol='tcp://*:')

port = socket.bind_to_random_port(communication_string, min_port=2000, max_port=8000)

print(port)

while True:
    socket.send_string("Server message to client3")
    time.sleep(1)
```

And I am receiving the exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/asaxena/Desktop/communciationExperiments/pair/tr.py", line 14, in <module>
port = socket.bind_to_random_port(communication_string, min_port=2000, max_port=8000)
  File "C:\Users\asaxena\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 256, in bind_to_random_port
self.bind('%s:%s' % (addr, port))
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 495, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:5653)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 25, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:10014)
raise ZMQError(errno)
zmq.error.ZMQError: No such device
```

However when I write the following code, everything works as I expect it to:

```
port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)

socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)
while True:
    socket.send_string("Server message to client3")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. The documentation does not seem to be of much help here. The function bind_to_random_port should find an open port assigned by system and use it, however that is not working right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the traceback in your question...

```
File "C:\Users\asaxena\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", 
line 256, in bind_to_random_port
  self.bind('%s:%s' % (addr, port))
```

You can see that the `zmq` module is building a connection string with '%s:%s' % (addr, port). So if you pass it the address `tcp://*:`, then you end up with `tcp://*::1234`.  Note the double `:`.

If you modify your code so that instead of this:

```
communication_string = "{protocol}".format(protocol='tcp://*:')
```

You have this:

```
communication_string = "{protocol}".format(protocol='tcp://*')
```

It should work as expected.  I've tested it locally and it seems to work for me.